# Asynchronous script dialog prompts in WebView2 on Windows

Tags: asynchronous, xamarin, uwp, maui, webview2

I'm developing a MAUI application in C# that implements a WebView2 and I need to change the style of the alert, prompt, and confirm dialogs. In WinUI applications everything is very modern, avoiding synchrony, but apparently only when it suits Microsoft, let me explain:
If I do:

```
webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDefaultScriptDialogsEnabled = false;
webView.CoreWebView2.ScriptDialogOpening += CustomScriptDialogOpening;
```

I can intercept the default JavaScript dialogs, but even if the `CustomScriptDialogOpening` function is async, the WebView doesn't await it.

So,

How the heck can I make a prompt if I can't await it,
And there's no way to launch the user prompt window synchronously, and if I launch it asynchronously, WebView2 doesn't await it?

I don't know if this has a solution...
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is e.GetDeferral();

This will allow to continue doing work async while wait for response.

Then you do e.Completed(); and it works properly.